# How to check compatibility of PL/SQL written for Oracle 9i but now to be migrated to Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-19c

I have lots of PL/SQL scripts which were developed years ago for an Oracle 9i application which should be migrated to Oracle 19c. I have read that normally there shouldn't be major changes in the PL/SQL language, but could be! Therefore i wanted to ask how i could check the compatibility of the PL/SQL statement for Oracle 19c? Is there any documentation or tool for this task?

Comment: Your unit, functional, and regression test suites will tell you if there are problems.

Comment: Understood, but how could i check this without Oracle Test Environment?

Comment: By creating a test environment and running all the scripts.

Comment: I don't think you should be concerned about functions. Usually functions are added by new releases but hardly removed. However, you may face new security functions. Operations which were possible in past releases are now not available by default because of enhanced security. Google for "Oracle xx New Features", then you should find documents of changes.

Comment: Maybe first check [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1) A client application which is able to connect to an Oracle 9i database will most likely not connect to an Oracle 19c database (and vice versa)